# c# - Appending dynamic value to JSON config value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to read a config from JSON file in my C# application. The scenario is such that the prefix is to be read from the config and the suffix is to be appended dynamically while reading.

**config.json**

```
{
  "Scenarios": [
    {
      "Name": "Flights",
      "IterationPrefix": "TeamIteration\\ABC\\123\\",
      "ParentLinkId": 123
    },
    {
      "Name": "Parcels",
      "IterationPrefix": "TeamIteration\\DEF\\234\\",
      "ParentLinkId": 234
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cars",
      "IterationPrefix": "TeamIteration\\FEG\\456\\",
      "ParentLinkId": 456
    }
  ]
}
```

The object mapping is as below
**ConfigMap.cs**

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public Scenario[] Scenarios;
}

public class Scenario
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Iteration { get; set; }

    public string ParentLinkId { get; set; }

    private string GetIterationSuffix()
    {
        var quarters = new[] { 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var month = currentDate.ToString("MMMM");
        var year = currentDate.Month <= 6 ? currentDate.Year : (currentDate.Year + 1);
        var quarter = quarters[currentDate.Month - 1];
        return "FY" + year + "\\Q" + quarter + "\\" + month;
    }
}
```

I want `Iteration` to be `IterationPrefix + GetIterationSuffix()`. Not sure exactly how can that be achieved.

I am trying to deserialize in the following way

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppConfig>(jsonstring);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make GetIterationSuffix static and internal then do this:

```
var scenarioDes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppConfig>(jsonstring);
scenarioDes.Iteration = GetIterationSuffix();
```